# Expect script + automated telnet process between three Linux machines

Tags: linux, expect, telnet, autologin

Is it possible to do the following by expect script?

I have Linux server that connected to **linux_machine1** and **linux_machine1** connected to **linux_machine2**

My Linux server have access only to **linux_machine1** ( linux server can telnet to **linux_machine1** but  can’t telnet to **linux_machine2**  )

But from **linux_machine1** I have access VIA telnet to **linux_machine2**

So my question is:

I need to develop expect script that perform telnet from the Linux server to **linux_machine1**

then expect will perform telnet to **linux_machine2** from **linux_machine1** and will copy the **/etc/hosts** file from **linux_machine2** to  my Linux server

Is this scenario can be implemented by expect script?

Short example that descript the process:

```
  ( run expect from Linux server ) --> linux_machine1 --> linux_machine2 
  Linux server          <--   /etc/hosts    from linux_machine2 <--
```

- remark - expect script need to be activate from the linux server

Comment: I guess you already know telnet is insecure and don't know if you can switch to ssh, which is more secure and solves your problem. If you are able to switch to ssh you can create a tunnel and access machine 2 through machine 1 from your linux box with just one simple ssh command (I think the parameter you need is -J).

Answer (score 0):

From **Linux_Server**, run the below script.

Don't use `telnet` as it is unencrypted. You can rather use `ssh` and `sftp` as below.

```
#This part connects to Machine1
#Just change username, password_here and Linux_machine1 to suit your requirement. 

#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet -l username linux_machine1
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "password_here\r"
send -- "\r"
expect eof

#Now we are connected to Linux_Machine1 from where we will connect to Linux_machine2
#Just change username, password_here and Linux_machine2 to suit your requirement. 

spawn ftp username@machine2
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "password_here\r"
send -- "\r"
expect eof
expect "ftp>"
send -- "get /etc/hosts\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "quit \r"
```

In your local folder of **Linux_Server**, a copy of `/etc/hosts` will be present.

**P.S**: Tested in local machine and works perfectly fine. If you still wish to use telnet, the above script will give you an idea on how to do it. You can modify the ssh and sftp connections to telnet as you desire.

**P.P.S**: I would really appreciate if you respond back with either bricks or compliments as I had spent good half an hour in preparing this script :) Ok, not half an hour, but definitely 15 minutes :)

Comment: I have a problem with your solution - linux_machine1/2 not have ssh , only telnet because they are very old linux machine , could you advice how to fit your script for telnet ?  ( remark I cant install ssh on the ,machines )

Comment: can I replace the ssh with telnet ?

Comment: I have made some changes. However, I could not test it as I do not have telnet in my server. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: ok I need to test it on my machine it will take time because I need to drive to my work , lets say 2 hours and I will give you feedbake

Comment: Sure. It is night for me here. If there is more issues, I will look into it tomorrow. Good night :)

Comment: Hi Ramesh , I am not sure if you can put expect eof more then once , any way in my linux machine seems that expect stop on the first expect eof